# Azure SQL handling special characters

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL (as database) with hibernate (as ORM) and Java as programming language, we have a address column which stores the address as a JSON, we are facing problem with storing special characters which are converted to  " ??? " (question mark)

Example: "Ω" is being stored as "?"

Tha table :

```sql
CREATE TABLE test.[order](.....
.......
[shipping_address] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
  .......
  .......
  )
```

### Thanks in advance.

This was first issue which we could solve with Column type (Nvarchar) and data-type in hibernate as String. It works fine with SQL-Server in local but in UAT which is azure-sql , it doesn't work.Both have same collation : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Mojibake - save as utf8?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to store it in a `varchar` column type that doesn't support the required collation. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69971447/edit) your question to include the table schema, including the column collation(s) - as text. If the column doesn't specify a particular collation, please also include the database's default collation.

Comment: How are you passing the value into SQL? Are you using parameters? If so are you passing those as `nvarchar`?